# Obtener un valor autoincrementable insertado previamente en MYSQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, mariadb

Ando haciendo un procedimiento almacenado para dar de alta un usuario en la base de datos. El campo del id del usuario es autoincrementable y por eso no lo pongo en el insert. Lo que sucede es que quiero obtener dentro del mismo proceso almacenado el valor de ese id que se asignó de manera automatica.

El codigo de mi proceso almacenado es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE alta_usuario (IN nip VARCHAR(4), IN tipo VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO Usuario (Nip, TipoUsuario)
        VALUES (nip, tipo);
    COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Como el id es autoincrementable pues no lo tengo como variable input del proceso, se pone automaticamente. La cuestión es querer saber que id le puso la base de datos ya que lo requiero para otro proceso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare ultimoId int(10);

select id into ultimoId 
from Usuario
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

Después de insertar el nuevo registro harías la consulta que te pongo arriba, lo que se hace aquí es declarar la **variable ultimoId** de tipo **int**, la cual nos va a servir como bien indica su nombre para almacenar el **id** del último registro introducido.

En esta consulta lo que se hace es **ordenar descendentemente** por el **campo Id** los registros de la **tabla Usuario**, de esta forma el último registro quedaría en la cima de la tabla y aplicando la **cláusula limit** obtenemos solamente ese último registro, del cual seleccionamos solamente su **Id**, quedando guardado en la **variable ultimoId**.